# &amp replace the string in apex string.unescapeHTML4() is not working

Tags: salesforce, apex

This code is storing the stage name in string format but one of the value contain `&` and because of it it showing `&amp` by replacing the string value

```
string stages = ''; //string type stages variable
for (string s :stagenames ){ //loop
    stages = +stages+s+':'; //assigning value to  the stages
    System.debug(stages.unescapeHTML4()); //getting all  the values  inside it one by one
}//but one string is jack & Jill so instead of showing actual string it just showed me 'jack &amp'
```

Comment: Hey Pranav.
I tried this:

`List<String> stagenames = new List<String>();
stagenames.add('jack');
stagenames.add(' ');
stagenames.add('&');
stagenames.add(' ');
stagenames.add('Jill');
string stages = ''; //string type stages variable
for (string s :stagenames ){ //loop
    stages = +stages+s+':'; //assigning value to  the stages
    System.debug(stages.unescapeHTML4()); //getting all  the values  inside it one by one
}//but one string is jack & Jill so instead of showing actual string it just showed me 'jack &amp'`


It is working fine

Comment: Out put of my last debug log was `jack: :&: :Jill:`